# User is unable to transfer records to other user with the same role and profile via the UI

Tags: ui, record-owner

Specifically referring to Account and Opportunity records on Lightning.
The user owns an opportunity record, when he clicks on the button to change owner, he only sees his name in the dropdown and when he types other people's names, nothing shows up.

The user has a custom profile, the profile has 'Transfer Records = true' and he has View All and Modify All permissions on Account and Opportunity.

What have I missed?

Comment: Can they see these other people's records (e.g. by navigating there with a URL?)

Comment: Yes they can see other people's records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the user wasn't able to see others is because the User object was set to private access (sharing settings), changing it from 'Private' to 'Public Read Only' resolved the issue.